# Can we maintain object for text inputs in redux form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am thinking to use redux Form for my application. 
can we maintain an object for text input types.
ex: I have one field Title so in redux store i want to main it as:

```
Title: {
  en_US: "This is in English",
  en_GB: "This is UK English",
  fr_FR: "This is in french"
}
```

So I have flags for selecting languages whenever i change the language my form should be rendered with the locale selected.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but it has nothing to do with `redux-form`. You could just render the label for an input independently:

```
<label>{this.props.myTextLabel}</label>
<Field id="myText" /> // Field comes from redux-form
```

Another option is to use a custom component and pass the title to it:

```
<Field id="myText" component={MyInput} label={this.props.myTextLabel} />

const MyInput = ({ ..., label }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" ... />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David for you reply , i think i have not clearly stated my problem here its not about label to a field , its all about the value of my title field so let me elaborate,  So for title field user can add different translation for same input field value (not label label is always fixed english) whenever user types something inside input field i check a state where i am maintaining the language Id selected, based on that i normalize the value as key value pair as shown above so in store it's maintained as key value pair to language id and value . and while displaying i am using format

Comment: as i mentioned i am able to achieve it through normalize and format but i am having problem while initializing the form in edit mode using initialValues, initially the form is getting loaded with initial values but suppose for the title field rendering when i am changing the flag from default english to china its not rerendering the form

Comment: Maybe you could just add some more code to see this in action, otherwise it's not so easy to understand what's going on. How is the language selection and form rendering bound together?